# Scala update object fields incrementally

Tags: scala

I need to build records with multiple fields.

The record definition is like:

```
class Record(
  f1: Int,
  f2: String,
  ...
  err: String
)
```

The logic is like:

```
record.f1 = get_f1()
record.f2 = get_f2()
...
```

The calls to get_f1 etc may throw exceptions. When this happen, we set record.err to the exception message.

Right now, my hacky solution is to use a mutable Record instance and patch the fields incrementally. When exception happens, I'll catch it from an outer function and set the err field.

The question is how can I implement this in a more functional way?

------ edit -----

We need the err field to output the first exception
When exception happens, we still want to output the fields already populated

Comment: What happens if two fields throw exceptions, which error is chosen? And what value do you give to those fields? How do you know which fields are in error and which are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is how can I implement this in a more functional way?

By properly modeling this in a functional style.

First, let's remove the `err` field from the `case class`, and rather use `Either`
Second, let's properly handle the `nulls` using `Option`
Finally, let's use a functional library like **cats**.

The end result would be something like this:

```scala
import cats.data.EitherNec
import cats.syntax.all._

type Error = String // You may use a better data type.

final case class Record(
  f1: Int,
  f2: String,
  f3: Boolean
)

object Record {
  def fromRawData(f1: Option[Int], f2: Option[String], f3: Option[Boolean]): EitherNec[Error, Record] =
    (
      f1.toRightNec(left = "F1 was empty"),
      f2.toRightNec(left = "F2 was empty"),
      f3.toRightNec(left = "F3 was empty")
    ).parMapN(Record.apply)
}
```

> The `EitherNec[E, A]` is just an alias for `Either[NonEmptyChain[E], A]` 
> Meaning that if it is a `Left` it will hold all the errors;
> it also implies that there must be at least one error.

Feel free to ask any follow-up questions you may have.

---

If you don't want to use **cats** you can replace the `parMapN` with a `for`; but this will stop at the first failure.

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/y9FS78AWRB6oBnfwrz8E7w/1)*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. The err field is to be saved together with already collected fields in case of an exception, so we know what's going wrong. And is it possible to have something with vanilla Scala? The cats library looks powerful, but it would be great to have fewer dependency

Comment: @songhc yes, just use `for` instead of `parMapN` but that will only contain the first failure instead of all. And for storing the results you still want to use an `Either` or some other custom data type instead of mixing error and real data in the same object. - PS: About dependencies, I refused to add **cats** just for a single function for so long that when I finally added it to my project I had to rewrite it almost from scratch.

Comment: I feel it is not literally replacing parMapN with for, could you share the sketch of the new code? wrt. err field, it is part of the output, thus we use it instead of Either

Comment: @songhc `for { f1Data <- f1; f2Data <- f2; f3Data <- f3 } yield Record(f1Data, f2Data, f3Data)` that is just basic **Scala**. Also, again about the error, it doesn't make much sense to the error to be part of the output but whatever you want, you would just need to manipulate the output produced by the `for`

Answer (score 2):

This is a (mostly) functional way of doing this:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

Try {
  Record(getf1(), getf2(), "")
} match {
  case Success(r) => r
  case Failure(e) => Record(0, "", e.getMessage)
}
```

If the code inside the `Try` runs OK then it will return `Success` and the `match` will extract the value and return it.

If the code throws an exception then it will be caught by the `Try` and it will return `Failure`. The `match` will catch the error code and then create a value of `Return` with `err` set to the error message from the exception.

---

As others have mentioned, the `Either` type is a better way of handling the error case as it removes the error information from the `Record` class itself:

```
Try {
  Record(getf1(), getf2())
}.toEither
```

The result will be `Right(<record>)` on success or `Left(<exception>)` on error. You can use `match` to determine which answer was given.

---

For the **modified question** you need to use a nested chain of `Try` calls, with one level of nesting for each field in the record.

```
Try(getf1()) match {
  case Failure(e) => Record(0, "", e.getMessage)
  case Success(f1) =>
    Try(getf2()) match {
      case Failure(e)  => Record(f1, "", e.getMessage)
      case Success(f2) => Record(f1, f2, "")
    }
}
```

This rather tortuous code is the consequence of the hybrid error handling approach in the question. A more standard design would do error handling for the whole record (as in the examples above) or for each individual field (by making each field an `Option` or `Either` value).

Comment: I think both your answer and Luis Miguel’s are pretty good, your’s is also beginner-friendly, but I think if you didn’t use zero values (0 and empty string) in case of failure, either by using Either(like Either[E, Record]) or Option (for fields) that would’ve been very better!

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. I'd like to still keep all the fields already collected, even when exception happens. Updated my question to make it clearer

Comment: How do you know which field was in error? What values go in the fields that weren't calculated because of earlier errors?

Comment: The fields usually have there own category of errors. And if an error happens, we will use default values for the fields not populated yet